# Filter data from bulk csv to small csv

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I have one raw sheet and that needs to be divided into certain templates.From the raw sheet(raw_data), I have one more sheet (man_data) in which whole data is present.I need to check the manufacturer(column E from raw_data) to be checked with (column C from man_data). If data is not present in the man_data then i need that data to be written in new template(manufacturer_template in column C(name)).

Please find below the template format of the sheet.

How can we write a program in a simple javascript code.I am very new at this and learning javascript now so  kindly help me out in writing the code.
Thanks.

Kindly let me know if you need any help regarding question description.

Please find attached files on below onedrive link.
https://1drv.ms/f/s!Asot5b-vLh9Qhlvu9HuMtlKMSmdV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read data using javascript.
then apply filter method of javascript to get filtered result...

`var data = [1,2,3,4,5];`
`data.filter(function(obj){ return obj>2  })`

Likewise above code return numbers greater than 2

You can write any logic in '{ }' of function

Comment: I need a code to start with,coz I am a beginner and currently not able to implement my thoughts on a code format.

Comment: Can you give sample data?? I will send you sample code

Comment: are you able to read csv files??  or you need help from reading csv file to filtering result and exporting csv again

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of doing things in a code format.It is like spoon feeding.I can only understand what is written in the code but still not able to write any.

Comment: I need help from reading the csv and then filtering till exporting the data in new csv.

Comment: Okay No issue.. I will explain step by step

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code to accept csv file:

```html
<input type="file" id="cvsFileChooser" accept=".csv" />
```

JavaScript code for reading and processing csv file

```js
 $('#cvsFileChooser').change(function() {
            var output = "";
            var csvInputFilesName = $('#cvsFileChooser').prop("files");         
                var file = csvInputFilesName[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    output = e.target.result;
                    displayContents(output);
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
                reader.onerror = function() {
                    alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
                };
            }
        });


function displayContents(txt) {
    var rows = txt.split('\n')// this will give each row array saperate from csv data
    for(i=0;i<row.length;i++){ // iteration upto the end of all rows
        var singleRow = rows[i]; // get each row
        var columnArray = singleRow.split(','); // get column array data for each row
        if(columnArray[ your excel column number to check data ] !="")
        {
            // your logic to copy data in new array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check above code and let me know if require any help